# While loop checking JBoss status down or not , giving error

Tags: linux, shell, unix

The intention of the following code is to check status of JBoss, the while loop iterates until the JBoss status comes to 'DOWN' state. `

```
    JBOSS_ROOT=/opt/app/jboss/jboss.sh

time=1
while  [ $JBOSS_ROOT status | egrep -nq "DOWN"  ]
  do
        echo "JBoss stooping, please wait ......."
        sleep 1m
        if [ $time -gt 6 ]
         then
            echo "Something went wrong.. it's been running more than 5 minutes, please check JBoos server log and deployments"
            exit
        fi

        time=$(expr "$time" + 1)
  done

echo "JBoss stopped"
```

`

> ```
> $JBOSS_ROOT status returns "JBoss DOWN" if JBoss in down( stop position).
> ```
>
> $JBOSS_ROOT status returns "JBoss (pid:32627) is RUNNING" if JBoss in running( start position).

throwing error at while loop. saying that ./stop.sh: line 5: [: missing]'

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown at while is because bash does not allow piping inside while as such

replace `while  [ $JBOSS_ROOT status | egrep -nq "DOWN"  ]` with

`while  [ $($JBOSS_ROOT status | egrep -nq "DOWN")  ]`

```
    JBOSS_ROOT=/opt/app/jboss/jboss.sh

time=1
while  [ $JBOSS_ROOT status | egrep -nq "DOWN"  ]
  do
        echo "JBoss stooping, please wait ......."
        sleep 1m
        if [ $time -gt 6 ]
         then
            echo "Something went wrong.. it's been running more than 5 minutes, please check JBoos server log and deployments"
            exit
        fi

        ((time=$time+1))
  done

echo "JBoss stopped"
```

Also `time=$(expr "$time" + 1)` won't work as you expect `time` would have value as `1+1`. 
you can use `((time=$time+1))` to evaluate the arithmatic expression.